# Что означает запись типа "urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26" в описании зависимостей модуля Python?

Tags: python, pip, зависимости

Пытаюсь установить в оффлайне модуль selenuim из скачанного файла. Он говорит, что ему не хватает `urllib3[socks]`. Модуль urllib3 я установил ранее, в качестве модуля он импортируется под именем urllib. А вот запись с квадратными скобками и именем socks внутри них я не понимаю. Внутри whl-файла есть файл METADATA, и в нём есть именно такая запись: `urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26`. Установленная версия urllib3 подходит под эти рамки. Чего ему ещё надо от меня ?

Comment: Кстати, все зависимости вместе с подзависимостями в виде whl файлов можно скачать через `pip wheel -w wheels/ -r requirements-remote.txt --pre --allow-all-external` (папка wheels/ должна существовать, в requirements-remote.txt - файл со списком зависимостей, ну еще `pip install wheel` нужно заранее установить), см. https://dizballanze.com/ru/python-wheels-dlia-bystroi-ustanovki-zavisimostei/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В квадратных скобках указывается имя набора опциональных зависимостей (дополнительных, не устанавливаемых по умолчанию). Чтобы они установились, например, через `pip`, нужно делать установку именно с квадратными скобками:
`pip install "urllib3[socks]"` (лучше - с указанием ограничений по версии, раз они в метаданных указаны, т.е. `pip install "urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26"`)

Чтобы понять, что за зависимости, нужно смотреть `setup.py` или `pyproject.toml` проекта, в данном случае - [`pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/pyproject.toml) (`setup.py` в проекте отсутствует). Смотрим раздел `[project.optional-dependencies]`:

```
[project.optional-dependencies]
brotli = [
  "brotli>=1.0.9; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'",
  "brotlicffi>=0.8.0; platform_python_implementation != 'CPython'"
]
zstd = [
  "zstandard>=0.18.0",
]
socks = [
  "PySocks>=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7",
]
```

Видим, что в группе `socks` указан пакет `PySocks`, значит нужно доустановить его.

В `setup.py` опциональные зависимости передаются в виде словаря в параметр `extras_require` функции `setup`, т.е. было бы что-то такое:

```py
...

setup(
   ...
    extras_require={
        "brotli": [
            "brotli>=1.0.9; platform_python_implementation == 'CPython'",
            "brotlicffi>=0.8.0; platform_python_implementation != 'CPython'",
        ]
        "zstd": ["zstandard>=0.18.0"],
        "socks": ["PySocks>=1.5.6,<2.0,!=1.5.7"],
    },
   ...
)

...
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, установка PySocks 1.7.1 не помогла. Сообщение при попытке установки Selenium осталось тем же (https://pastebin.com/vCfFjSmn):
ERROR: No matching distribution found for urllib3[socks]<3,>=1.26 (from selenium==4.14.0)

Comment: Сам urllib3 установлен?

Comment: Я, кажется, запутался. Точно, там есть urllib, а urllib3 нужной версии не встаёт. Встаёт только версия 1.21, а его не хватает.  Версия 2.0.7 требует hatchling, а он хочет ещё кучу всего. Сейчас попробую распутаться.

Comment: Я сообразил наконец, что не надо гнаться за последней версией модуля. Взял urllib3 ближе к той версии, которую просил selenuim - 1.28. И всё получилось. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @ВадимСухотин если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Comment: Хорошо, что подсказали, а то я здесь новичок.